# How can I save and restore a beamer template?

Tags: beamer

Is it possible to save and restore the specification of a `beamer` template?

- In this specific case, I would like to save and restore the
  `background canvas` template.

Alternatively (even better, in fact), is it possible to limit the scope of a template specification?

- The thought here is that it is possible to do this with things like
  font switches and colour changes (stick curly brackets around
  `\sffamily` or `\color{red}` to limit the scope). Is there an
  equivalent for changes to `beamer` templates?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading][top=blue!20,bottom=blue!20,middle=blue!5,midpoint=.5]
\newcommand*{\canvasdu}{\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading][top=black!90,bottom=black!90,middle=black!70,midpoint=.5]}

\title[Short title]{Title}
\author{Mari Jones}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \titlepage
  \end{frame}

  {\canvasdu
  \begin{frame}
    \color{red}A special frame
  \end{frame}}

  \begin{frame}
    A bog-standard frame
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Template transformations]

That is, I would like to restore the original configuration of `background canvas` for the third frame **without knowing that it used blue vertical shading**.

Another possibility I've wondered about is *cloning* the template in the `\canvasdu` command. However, this strikes me as a somewhat inelegant approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you choose a template in a group, the effect of this choice is scoped to this group. But here, you choose the same template but you change its definition (the used colors).

Here is a solution defining a new `background canvas` named `my vertical shading`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading]%
[top=blue!20,bottom=blue!20,middle=blue!5,midpoint=.5]

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate{background canvas}{my vertical shading}%
[1][top=black!90,bottom=black!90,middle=black!70,midpoint=.5]
{\pgfuseshading{my@beamer@backgroundshading}}
[action]
{
  \beamer@calcvertshading{my@beamer@backgroundshading}{\the\paperwidth}{#1}
  \colorlet{my@beamer@@average}{beamer@average}
  \setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=my@beamer@@average}
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\canvasdu}{
  \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[my vertical shading]
}

\title[Short title]{Title}
\author{Mari Jones}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \titlepage
  \end{frame}

  {\canvasdu
  \begin{frame}
    \color{red}A special frame
  \end{frame}}

  \begin{frame}
    A bog-standard frame
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks really useful. Thank you. I will try this out shortly but +1 in the meantime. Also, it gives me another idea...

Comment: I'm accepting this - thank you! It didn't exactly end up working for me but it formed the core of a solution which I hacked together this afternoon. (Feels a bit fragile but seems to be working so far.)

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty, maybe inelegant, but...

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\normalcanvas}{\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading][top=blue!20,bottom=blue!20,middle=blue!5,midpoint=.5]}
\newcommand{\specialcanvas}{\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading][top=black!90,bottom=black!90,middle=black!70,midpoint=.5]}
\newenvironment{canvasdu}{\specialcanvas}{\normalcanvas}
\normalcanvas

\title[Short title]{Title}
\author{Mari Jones}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \titlepage
  \end{frame}

\begin{canvasdu}
  \begin{frame}
    \color{red}A special frame
  \end{frame}
\end{canvasdu}

  \begin{frame}
    A bog-standard frame
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks but to do this I have to know what the original colours are in order to define `\normalcanvas`. I really need a solution which does not depend on this. (I want to set this up in a class which provides commands I can use independently of the particular look of a set of slides.) Right now I basically use `\canvasdu` and `\canvasarferol` where `\canvasarferol` is defined much as you've defined `\normalcanvas` but that definition has to be specific to the document to ensure the right colours and I was hoping for a more general solution.